# Advanced css form selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hello guys I have this CSS selector and I can't figure out how to read it. Can someone explain? Thanks

```
.form__input:not(:placeholder-shown).form__input:not(:focus)+.form__label {
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ideal is that in nested css classes you put them one below the other for easy reading, since it can contain many elements and about your question

```css
.form__input:not(:placeholder-shown) 
// apply the class to all .form__input that do not have the selector "placeholder-shown".
.form__input:not(:focus) // applies the css to all .form__input not in "focus".
+.form__label // here applies the css to the input label
{
```